# Continuous ID in different tables

Tags: php, sql

Here is the correction/update of my first post :)

I have a website where i can add news. If i add a news-entry, it will create a database entry on table "news" with a unique id for each news-entry.

In every news-entry, i can add multiple pictures and multiple text-sections. For each picture which i add, it will create a database entry on table "news_images" with a unique image_id (autoincrement) and with the id from the table "news" (so i know which image belongs to which news-entry) . Same procedure if i add a text-section.

The problem that i have: The pictures and the text-sections in each news-entry are draggable, so i can change their position (up and down). I must save each position for every object in the database. For this i added now a new Table "news_imgid_txtid". But i still don't know how to add a continuous id..

Example:

- I add a image in the news-entry(id 234). So the image_id in table "news_images" will be 62
  (autoincrement).
- in table "news_imgid_txtid" the value 62 should be
  written in row "id" (don't know yet how to do this but will find it
  out).
- I add a text-section in the news-entry(id 234). So the
  text_id in table "news_text" will be 18 (autoincrement) but should be 63 (don't know how
  to do this)

[image]

Thanks for your help, Misch

Comment: Tag dbms used. Give us table definitions. On the other hand, why bother?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Can you clarify?  Do you mean that you want all identifiers in your database to be universally unique?  What is it that you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: this is not logical... `news_image` and `news_text` should not share their id...

Comment: Can anybody help me? I figured out how to write the same values for image_id/text_id in table news_imgid_txtid -> LAST_INSERT_ID() but now i am stucked...

Answer (score 2):

IMO for your case you should change tables' structure. First create a header table `media_header` for instance. The `media_header` table should contain an `id` column. Than every table `news_image`, `news_text` should have an foreign key from `news_text.text_id` and `news_image.image_id` columns to `media_header.id` column. Than the DB will preserve this id as continuous.

Comment: @jarlh I won't argue if there are better :)

Comment: @jarlh I agree with you he should do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have an id column that is unique across tables, you want to use a [GUID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/05/27/guid-vs-int-debate.aspx). The details on how to do that will depend on your sql engine.

However, it is not clear whether this is actually the best design for you. If you will give us more information on *why* you want to do this, we could probably point you in a better direction.